# How do you develop Apps with PhoneGap?

Tags: web-applications

Do you create an application for browsers and then you port it to PhoneGap or you have to rebuild the APK every time you make a single change on HTML/CSS/JS?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a ["getting started"](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/phonegap-from-scratch/) tutorial.

Basically, yes, ytoyu have to rebuild the APK - what you're doing with Cordova (the new name for phonegap) is build an app using html-based tools. You do not host the html on a server.